# Whats the best way to implement an AJAX timeout?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I trying to make the AJAX request time-out if the web server goes down.  Does anyone have a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery offers a beautiful solution

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    timeout: 5000,
    url: "myurl.com",

    success: function(data) {
        alert('Data load: '+ data);
    },

    error: function(){
        alert('Error loading data');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what framework are you using. For example [`jQuery.ajax`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax) support a `timeout` option that does this. You can also set it globally using [`jQuery.ajaxSetup`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajaxSetup).